# sphinx-4 building. Apache ant

Tags: java, ant, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

i am trying to build the sphinx-4 program on my pc, but i am stuck on this step.

> To build Sphinx-4, at the command prompt change to the directory where
>   you installed Sphinx-4 (usually, a simple "cd sphinx4" will do). Set
>   required environment variables. JAVA_HOME to the location of JDK,
>   ANT_HOME to the location of ant and and PATH to include both bin
>   subfolder of JDK and bin subfolder of ant variables.

Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: To do what exactly? You do not know how to set environment variables, do you?

Comment: no i do not.i dont get this whole step at all.

Comment: You can learn how to set environment variables from google, it depends on your os, try to google "set environment variable windows" or "set environment variable linux"

Comment: is there anyway where i can ask you or similar speech recognition experts whenever i have a question*( like a tag) because im working on a software and it would be very helpful to directly ask you guys and get help directly.

Comment: There is #cmusphinx channel on freenode for that.